# Let $G$ be a group of order $n$ and $m$ be relatively prime to $n$; given that $g^m=e$, show that $g$ is an identity element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $n$ and $m$ be relatively prime to $n$; given that $g^m=e$, show that $g$ is an identity element.

(In other words, I will have to show its order is one.)

I think there are different approaches to solve this question, it could be solved by using one of the Lagrange's theorems results starting off with $g^n=e$ (and I know how to prove this part) , and $\gcd(m,n)=1$ but  I seem to be stuck here. I can't seem to connect the information correctly to lead me to the answer required.

Kindly would anyone explain me the steps clearly ?

Answer (score 5):

The fact that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime means that there exist integers $r$ and $s$ such that $1 = mr + ns$. Therefore:
$$\begin{aligned}
g &= g^1 \\
&= g^{mr + ns} \\
&= g^{mr}g^{ns} \\
&= (g^m)^r (g^n)^s \\
&= 1^r 1^s \\
&= 1
\end{aligned}$$
Line 5 follows from line 4 because $g^m = 1$ by assumption and $g^n = 1$ by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Now i know what i was forgetting!! Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

[Lagrange's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) $\Rightarrow g^n=1\,$ [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2950905/242) $\ g^m = 1^m\Rightarrow\, g = 1,\,$ by raising  to power $\,\frac{1}m \bmod n\,$

---

${\bf Or}\  \ \ o(g)\mid\color{c00} m\ $ by $\,g^m = 1\, $ and the [Order Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242)

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ o(g)\mid \color{#}n = |G|\ $ by [Lagrange's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242)

$\ \Rightarrow \ o(g) = 1\ $ by $\,\color{c00}m,\color{0a0}n\,$ coprime, by hypothesis.

**Remark** $ $ Generally $\,o(g)\mid m,n\iff o(g)\mid \gcd(m,n)\ $ by  the [gcd Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242).